# KASLR disabled: could not find suitable E820 region!

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualbox

I´ve had  many problems installing Ubuntu in VirtualBox. The last one is this:

[image]

Can you help me? I hope yes. 
Ty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Boot Fix

In order to boot properly in the first place, highlight your Ubuntu option and press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit the boot parameters. Manually insert `nokaslr` behind `quiet splash` and then press <kbd>F10</kbd> to continue booting.

## Permanent Fix

Using `sudo` powers edit your `/etc/default/grub` and add the option `nokaslr` to the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nokaslr"
```

You may have other options besides `quiet splash` which you will want to leave in place. Save the file and exit your editor. Then run:

```
sudo update-grub
```

## Second Option

If inserting `nokaslr` above doesn't work, then repeat both sections above but insert `kaslr` instead.

## TL;DR

KASLR randomizes the layout of Kernel address space making it harder for snooping programs to hack kernel working storage and obtain passwords. It was superceded by KAISER which was superceded KPTI (Kernel Page Table Isolation) for Meltdown and Spectre Security hole violations.

Answer (score 2):

The error is clear actually, you just need to allocate more memory.

From System menu set enough memory, >1GB and be sure you have enough memory in your base system.

It worked for me.

Comment: Davut is absolutely correct. I got the `physical kaslr disabled` error when trying to restore a **Windows 95** image to **VirtualBox** using **Clonezilla** The foolish error that I made was to configure the VM with sufficient resources for Win 95, *not* the resources needed for Clonezilla to run. Increasing the RAM fixed the error